# Display restaurant options based on dietary restrictions

Tags: c++

This is a fairly basic question but for some reason, I can't put it together. What I am trying to do is have a user input Y/N about dietary restrictions. For example:

Is anyone in your party a vegetarian? Y 
Is anyone in your party a vegan? N 
Is anyone in your party gluten-free? Y

Here are your restaurant choices: 
Main Street Pizza Company
Corner Café 
The Chef’s Kitchen

I tried the following: (I'm still pretty new at C++ so please forgive this nooby question.

```
char Y;
int vegan;
int vegetarian;
int glutenFree;
int restrictions;

cout << "Is anyone in your party vegan? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> vegan;

cout << "Is anyone in your party vegetarian? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> vegetarian;

cout << "Is anyone in your party gluten free? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> glutenFree;


switch (restrictions) {
    case 'a':
        if(vegan == Y)
            cout << "The following resturants offer vegan options" << endl << "Corner Café, The Chef’s Kitchen" << endl;
        break;

    case 'b':
        cout << "Is anyone in your party vegetarian? (Y/N)" << endl;
        if(vegetarian == Y)
            cout << "The following resturants offer vegetarian options" << endl << "Main Street Pizza Company, Corner Café, Mama’s Fine Italian, The Chef’s Kitchen" << endl;
            break;

    case 'c':
        cout << "Is anyone in your party gluten free? (Y/N)" << endl;
        if(glutenFree == Y)
            cout << "The following resturants offer gluten-free options" << endl << "Main Street Pizza Company,The Chef’s Kitchen, Corner Café" << endl;
            break;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is restrictions supposed to be?

Comment: Specify exactly what the problem is. Do you get an error?

Comment: Restrictions are supposed to be vegan, gluten-free, and vegetarian. As for errors really an error but once it asks the first cout I input Y and it just runs the rest of the code without me entering a Y or N for the other questions

Comment: The `restrictions` is an *integer* variable, but you are comparing it against characters.  Also, you don't initialize it nor set the value before the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Y` is not initialized, so you probably want to do something like `char Y = 'Y'`.

Then in your `switch` statement, you don't cover cases when condition `(vegan == Y)`, `(vegetarian == Y)`, `(glutenFree == Y)` are not met. So you will get output only in cases when user has answered `Y`. Nothing will be displayed if he picks `N`.

Also, if you want to store `char`s I don't see a reason to store them as `int`s. You should make `vegan`, `vegetarian` and `glutenFree` `char`s.

Comment: So in order to solve the problem of nothing being displayed when the user enters 'N' I can add an else if statement? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @zleff Yes, and you should use `char` to store `chars`, see edited answer.

Comment: It's a wee bit worse than  just a simple "Why store as `int`?" `cin >>` to an `int` will not accept letters, making the user's input to this program somewhat cryptic. To get `'a'`, they'll probably have to type in 97.